# Get value with php and mysql in var name[value1,value2,value2]

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

How I can insert array value in php and mysql from variable Var s1, s2, s3:

```
$(function () {

    var s1 = [100, 200, 300]; //How to Get Value from mysql database
    var s2 = [30, 80, 90]; //How to Get Value from mysql database
    var s3 = [120, 90, 80]; //How to Get Value from mysql database

    // Can specify a custom tick Array.
    // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.

    var ticks = ['2010', '2011', '2012'];
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {

        // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
        // be applied to all series in the chart.

        seriesDefaults: {
            shadow: true, // show shadow or not.
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                fillToZero: true
            }
        },

        // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
        // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
        // is specified for each series.

        series: [
            {label: 'Hotel'},
            {label: 'Event Regristration'},
            {label: 'Airfare'}
        ],

        // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
        // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
        // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
        // the legend to overflow the container.

        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid'
        },
        axes: {
            // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
            // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
            // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
            yaxis: {
                pad: 1.05,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '$%d'
                }
            }
        },
        grid: {
            borderColor: '#000', // CSS color spec for border around grid.
            borderWidth: 2.0, // pixel width of border around grid.
            shadow: true // draw a shadow for grid.
        }
    });
    // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
    // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
    // clicked along with the data for that point.
    $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',

    function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        $('#info3').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get data from database and store it in javascript variable?

Comment: Yes its   var s1 = [100, 200, 300]; //How to Get Value from mysql database
    var s2 = [30, 80, 90]; //How to Get Value from mysql database
    var s3 = [120, 90, 80]; //How to Get Value from mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways:

## Ajax

Use: $.getJSON   ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ )

```
var ses = {};

$.getJSON('page_adress.php', {variable_you_want_to_pass1: 'its value', variable_you_want_to_pass2: 'var 2 value'}, function(data) {
    ses = data;
});
```

In your PHP:

```
<?php
$passed_var_1 = $_REQUEST['variable_you_want_to_pass1'];
//.... etc


//Here you get your data from mysql, cast it into array

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dbdata);
?>
```

So basically after request finishes you will have exact array you had in PHP transferred in JavaScript. Have in mind that this technique uses AJAX. If you want to avoid that, you will have to use second technique.

## Dynamically Creating JS

Make PHP generate your javascript. In this case you would have in your main page

```
<script src="js_data.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In your `js_data.js.php` file:

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

$s1 = array(100,200,300);
//....

var s1 = [<?=implode(', ', $s1)?>],
    s2 = [<?=implode(', ', $s2)?>],
    s3 = [<?=implode(', ', $s3)?>];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First method (w/o ajax & json)(untidy-way)

First fetch the value from database and have it in PHP variable.
Then put html element in page and assign the value to it.
Then use it in javascript using document.getElement method.

// assume that you have got value from database in $valueFrmDB.

```
$valueFrmDB;
```

Now, take html element(you might have to take more than one)

```
<input type="hidden" id="something" name="something" value="echo value of $valueFrmDB here" />;
```

Then, in javascript

```
var vfd = document.getElementById('something').value;
```

convert string to array

#### Second method(with ajax and json)(simple & correct but must know ajax and json)

Use ajax to fetch the values from database
Then use json to pass that values to javascript

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do this by:

```
<?php
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendence");
   $results = array(array());

   while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $results[] = $line;
   }
?>
```

Javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var data = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>; //array uses here
     var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
       { 
       seriesDefaults: {
       renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {
        showDataLabels: true}
       }, 
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
      });
     });
  </script>
```